# Venetian word pairs — part 2

Tags: wordplay

A previous posting introduced the concept of [Venetian word pairs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77968/venetian-word-pairs-i-e-sectioned-word-reversals).  Relaxing the rules a bit opens a whole new world of Venetian word pairs.

Let's allow the transformation to use sections which may consist of a single letter.  Obviously, the reversal of a single letter is just itself again.

So SORCERESS becomes RECROSSES:

```
1. SORCERESS
2. SORCER ES S
3. RECROS SE S
4. RECROSSES
```

The hint for the above might be something like:

> female wizard
>   <===>  The tiger continually _________ his territory in search of prey and intruders

Now see how many of the below you can solve:

```
1.  a fan of Peter, Ivan, Nicholas, Catherine, and all the rest
    <===>  Dire _______

2.  ______ the number until the call goes through
    <===>  Emergency!  We've had a train ______

3.  Can you believe that people used to carry these fireworks around in their cars
    in case of emergency?
    <===>  more wrong than wrong

4.  no clothes
    <===>  clothes are scattered all over the floor

5.  Why, Mrs. Winthrop, you're looking quite ______ this evening!
    <===>  ______ball

6.  In youth, heights increase.  In middle age, ______ increase.
    <===>  Bill of ______

7.  The longer the baby goes without a nap, the _______ he becomes
    <===>  a split

8.  big dog patrols the ski slopes
    <===>  marketers' reset

9.  Applaud all you want, this orchestra never comes back out for _______
    <===>  Surgeons removed the tissue before it started to _______

10.  The battlefield was strewn with _______
     <===>  creative _______

11.  mathematical shape with infinite complexity
     <===>  boxcar train or _______ train

12.  calm
     <===>  seen again

13.  anything relating to marriage
     <===>  If you can braid hair then you can also undo the braids

14.  six-legged animal
     <===>  She's the ______ person I've ever met!

15.  often found in a fireplace holding the coals
     <===>  very weird

16.  edible shellfish
     <===>  it can't be added up

17.  get back together again
     <===>  known more commonly as a posse or an entourage

18.  This ______ some interesting questions
     <===>  comes up

19.  The British press ________ Winston Churchill
     <===>  Hand lotion leaves a feeling of ________ that I dislike

20.  To smooth down this rough wood, you'll need a ______
     <===>  caught in a net

21.  all the ceremonial stuff around royalty
     <===>  the price of sending goods by train

22.  This extravagant staircase is even _______ than the last!
     <===>  unusual word for snarled

23.  Interest _______ in a bank account
     <===>  to put a witchy spell on

24.  one after the other
     <===>  If you enjoyed sailing it the first time then why not again?

25.  He's not just a pastry chef, he's a true ______
     <===>  Some ______ you're just born with

26.  They don't appreciate my dirty jokes because they're all a bunch of ______
     <===>  lips were pressed together tightly

27.  Maybe I really ought to tone down the ________ of my jokes
     <===>  I guess if you can have several kinds of old laces then you can also have several kinds of ________

28.  This tropical drink is made with ______ of mango, papaya, and guava
     <===>  to read very carefully

29.  a place to store your clothes
     <===>  obscure carpentry term relating to the hole drilled for pinning a mortise-and-tenon joint
```

---

<strike>**Unsolved: 7, 19, 22**</strike> All have been solved

Comment: Most of these puzzles would be fine just as stand-alone anagram puzzles, and the extra constraint that they function like "venetian blinds" only narrows it down a little bit.

Comment: @Frpzzd — Yes, and I also enjoy figuring out how the transformation goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL ANSWER** with much help from @Nicolas Budig and @JohnMark Perry

1 (@Nicolas Budig):

> TSARIST <-> STRAITS

2 (@Nicolas Budig):

> REDIAL <-> DERAIL

3:

> FLARES  <=> FALSER

4 (@JohnMark_Perry):

> NUDITY -> NU DIT Y -> UN TID Y -> UNTIDY

5:

> LOVELY <=> VOLLEY

6:

> GIRTHS <=> RIGHTS

7:

> FUSSIER <=> FISSURE

8:

> BERNARD  <=> REBRAND

9:

> ENCORES <===> NECROSE

10 (@Nicolas Budig):

> CORPSES <-> PROCESS

11:

> FRACTAL <=> FLATCAR

12:

> SERENE <=>  RESEEN

13:

> NUPTIAL <=> UNPLAIT

14 (@Nicolas Budig):

> INSECT <-> NICEST

15:

> BRAZIER <=> BIZARRE

16 (@JohnMark_Perry):

> MUSSELS -> MUS SEL S -> SUM LES S -> SUMLESS

17 (@Nicolas Budig):

> REUNITE <-> RETINUE

18:

> RAISES <=> ARISES

19:

> OILINESS <=> LIONISES

20:

> SANDER <=> SNARED

21 (@JohnMark_Perry):

> REGALIA -> R EGALIA -> R AILAGE -> RAILAGE

22:

> GRANDER <=> GNARRED

23 (@Nicolas Budig):

> ACCRUES <-> ACCURSE

24:

> SERIAL <=> RESAIL

25 (@JohnMark_Perry):

> ARTIST -> ART I ST -> TRA I TS -> TRAITS

26:

> PRUDES <=> PURSED

27:

> RACINESS <=>  ARSENICS

28:

> PUREES <=> PERUSE

29 (@JohnMark_Perry):

> WARDROBE -> WARD ROB E -> DRAW BOR E -> DRAWBORE

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete, just posting a couple as I see them.

1.

> TSARIST <-> STRAITS

2.

> REDIAL <-> DERAIL

10.

> CORPSES <-> PROCESS

14.

> INSECT <-> NICEST

17.

> REUNITE <-> RETINUE

23.

> ACCRUES <-> ACCURSE

will post more as I figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

4.

> NUDITY -> NU DIT Y -> UN TID Y -> UNTIDY

6.

> GIRTHS -> GIR TH S -> RIG HT S -> RIGHTS

16.

> MUSSELS -> MUS SEL S -> SUM LES S -> SUMLESS

21.

> REGALIA -> R EGALIA -> R AILAGE -> RAILAGE

25.

> ARTIST -> ART I ST -> TRA I TS -> TRAITS

29.

> WARDROBE -> WARD ROB E -> DRAW BOR E -> DRAWBORE